# Linux out of memory killer kills process when there is more than enough memory available

Tags: memory-usage, oom, oom-killer

We are running a 64-Bit Ubuntu and our 32GB of physical memory is split into 3 zones (DMA: 16MB, DMA32: 4GB and Normal: 30GB). According to the dmesg logs printed below our system ran out of free memory on the Normal zone. The logs show that free memory is below the low limit and therefore is heavily starting to swap.

```
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] Node 0 Normal free:63692kB min:61368kB low:76708kB high:92052kB active_anon:13819020kB inactive_anon:1390260kB active_file:324kB inactive_file:736kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:30408704kB managed:29882588kB mlocked:0kB dirty:4kB writeback:0kB mapped:4708kB shmem:4860kB slab_reclaimable:75272kB slab_unreclaimable:35816kB kernel_stack:7312kB pagetables:35924kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:652kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:908 all_unreclaimable? no
```

Unfortunately our swap space of 2GB also ran full:

```
Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] Free swap  = 0kB
Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] Total swap = 2097148kB
```

We could add more swap space or reduce the memory over-committment on our system. But there is one thing we would like to understand before we do that: We calculated together all the rss pages that are reported by the kernel in the dmesg logs. The sum results in 4083166 pages which is about 16GB or Memory.
We would expect to see a lot more of our 32GB of memory reserved.

Who uses the rest of the memory and how could we trace this down?

Please find below the complete dmesg log reported by the oom-killer:

```
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [main]-pipeline invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x24201ca, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [main]-pipeline cpuset=3a8d1e7785d259036358f790d6bcd25682f2296f7f5aae4007122a62345b283d mems_allowed=0
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] CPU: 4 PID: 13956 Comm: [main]-pipeline Tainted: G             L  4.4.0-87-generic #110-Ubuntu
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 09/17/2015
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019]  0000000000000286 d31b6617973a4be6 ffff88028d4bf9f8 ffffffff813f9903
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019]  ffff88028d4bfbb0 ffff880819b24600 ffff88028d4bfa68 ffffffff8120b75e
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019]  ffffffff8113f98a ffff88028d4bfa98 ffffffff811a722d ffff88081bf15460
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] Call Trace:
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019]  [<ffffffff813f9903>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019]  [<ffffffff8120b75e>] dump_header+0x5a/0x1c5
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019]  [<ffffffff8113f98a>] ? __delayacct_freepages_end+0x2a/0x30
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019]  [<ffffffff811a722d>] ? do_try_to_free_pages+0x2ed/0x410
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019]  [<ffffffff81192ce2>] oom_kill_process+0x202/0x3c0
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019]  [<ffffffff81193109>] out_of_memory+0x219/0x460
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019]  [<ffffffff811990f8>] __alloc_pages_slowpath.constprop.88+0x938/0xad0
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019]  [<ffffffff81199516>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x286/0x2a0
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019]  [<ffffffff811e305c>] alloc_pages_current+0x8c/0x110
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019]  [<ffffffff8118f2ab>] __page_cache_alloc+0xab/0xc0
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019]  [<ffffffff811917ba>] filemap_fault+0x14a/0x3f0
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019]  [<ffffffff812a3736>] ext4_filemap_fault+0x36/0x50
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019]  [<ffffffff811be7d0>] __do_fault+0x50/0xe0
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019]  [<ffffffff811c22f2>] handle_mm_fault+0xfa2/0x1820
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019]  [<ffffffff8106b577>] __do_page_fault+0x197/0x400
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019]  [<ffffffff8106b802>] do_page_fault+0x22/0x30
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019]  [<ffffffff81844038>] page_fault+0x28/0x30
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] Mem-Info:
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] active_anon:3623939 inactive_anon:519706 isolated_anon:0
                            active_file:98 inactive_file:206 isolated_file:0
                            unevictable:0 dirty:1 writeback:0 unstable:0
                            slab_reclaimable:20794 slab_unreclaimable:9765
                            mapped:1178 shmem:3190 pagetables:10160 bounce:0
                            free:50583 free_pcp:183 free_cma:0
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] Node 0 DMA free:15860kB min:32kB low:40kB high:48kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15992kB managed:15908kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:16kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 2940 32122 32122 32122
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] Node 0 DMA32 free:122780kB min:6180kB low:7724kB high:9268kB active_anon:676736kB inactive_anon:688564kB active_file:68kB inactive_file:88kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:3129280kB managed:3048596kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:4kB shmem:7900kB slab_reclaimable:7904kB slab_unreclaimable:3228kB kernel_stack:688kB pagetables:4716kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:2140 all_unreclaimable? yes
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 29182 29182 29182
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] Node 0 Normal free:63692kB min:61368kB low:76708kB high:92052kB active_anon:13819020kB inactive_anon:1390260kB active_file:324kB inactive_file:736kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:30408704kB managed:29882588kB mlocked:0kB dirty:4kB writeback:0kB mapped:4708kB shmem:4860kB slab_reclaimable:75272kB slab_unreclaimable:35816kB kernel_stack:7312kB pagetables:35924kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:652kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:908 all_unreclaimable? no
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 0
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] Node 0 DMA: 1*4kB (U) 0*8kB 1*16kB (U) 1*32kB (U) 1*64kB (U) 1*128kB (U) 1*256kB (U) 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 1*2048kB (M) 3*4096kB (M) = 15860kB
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] Node 0 DMA32: 6560*4kB (UME) 1162*8kB (UME) 832*16kB (ME) 1143*32kB (UME) 587*64kB (UME) 4*128kB (M) 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 123504kB
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] Node 0 Normal: 14276*4kB (UME) 609*8kB (MH) 3*16kB (H) 1*32kB (H) 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 1*512kB (H) 1*1024kB (H) 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 63592kB
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] 58196 total pagecache pages
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] 54643 pages in swap cache
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] Swap cache stats: add 18366740, delete 18312097, find 6820279/8173012
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] Free swap  = 0kB
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] Total swap = 2097148kB
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] 8388494 pages RAM
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] 151721 pages reserved
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] 0 pages cma reserved
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] 0 pages hwpoisoned
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes nr_pmds swapents oom_score_adj name
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [  306]     0   306    10968     1627      25       4      533             0 systemd-journal
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [  344]     0   344    25742       36      17       4      534             0 lvmetad
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [  722]     0   722     7318       30      19       3       31             0 cron
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [  727]   106   727    10752      129      25       4       39          -900 dbus-daemon
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [  780]     0   780    69900      465      38       3       70             0 accounts-daemon
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [  782]     0   782     7163       42      19       3       46             0 systemd-logind
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [  787]     0   787    76201      555     104       3    28939             0 vmtoolsd
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [  843]     0   843     4901       51      14       3       35             0 irqbalance
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [  856]     0   856   273330     4976     117       6     4094          -500 dockerd
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [ 1106]     0  1106     4058       22      13       3       14             0 agetty
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [19618]   108 19618    27567      124      24       4       93             0 ntpd
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [22824]   104 22824    83051      279      30       4       93             0 rsyslogd
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [ 6763]     0  6763    11007      108      21       3        0         -1000 systemd-udevd
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [ 4730]     0  4730   214969     2443      50       6      196          -500 docker-containe
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [13392]     0 13392     5105       14      14       3       29             0 daemon
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [13393]     0 13393   183580     1886      43       5     1251             0 prometheus-node
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [13786]     0 13786   103424        0      26       5      187          -500 docker-containe
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [13805]  1000 13805      276        0       4       2       13             0 tini
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [13871]  1000 13871  1586068   133739     811      10   220384             0 java
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [ 4506]     0  4506    16377       18      36       3      160         -1000 sshd
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [25171]     0 25171    45485        0      18       5      144          -500 docker-proxy
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [25183]     0 25183    31150        0      18       5      659          -500 docker-proxy
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [25190]     0 25190    87040      713      25       5       82          -500 docker-containe
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [25208]  2000 25208     4915        1      14       3       81             0 artifactory_sta
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [25291]  2000 25291     4948        1      15       3      113             0 artifactory.sh
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [25320]  2000 25320  7879838  3931096    8163      26   184030             0 java
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [27475]     0 27475    23199       68      49       3      166             0 sshd
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [27478]  1013 27478    11312        0      27       3      212             0 systemd
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [27483]  1013 27483    15322      105      33       3      382             0 (sd-pam)
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [27502]  1013 27502    23199       51      47       3      181             0 sshd
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [27503]  1013 27503     6055      316      17       3      492             0 bash
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [29901]     0 29901    23199      233      50       3        0             0 sshd
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [29903]  1006 29903    11312      173      26       3        0             0 systemd
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [29905]  1006 29905    15322      209      33       3      278             0 (sd-pam)
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [29925]  1006 29925    23199      231      47       3        0             0 sshd
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [29926]  1006 29926     6571      811      19       3        0             0 bash
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [30400]  1006 30400   152391     1805      46       5        0             0 docker
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [30411]     0 30411   101375      670      25       6      511          -500 docker-containe
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] [30428]     0 30428     4967      139      14       3        0             0 bash
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] Out of memory: Kill process 25320 (java) score 470 or sacrifice child
[Fri Feb  8 15:42:54 2019] Killed process 25320 (java) total-vm:31519352kB, anon-rss:15724384kB, file-rss:0kB
```